# How do I add 3rd party voices to Narrator in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, text-to-speech, text-to-speech-voices, narrator

I'm looking for the best method to change the existing text-to-speech voice in Narrator to a 3rd party SAPI 5 voice I installed for text-to-speech programs.

Information about this has been very scarce from what I could find. I did attempt a [registry edit](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/114126-customize-narrator-voice-windows-10-a.html) using option six of the guide I found. But I was unable to find the value described in the guide. My only options appeared to be [Braille and RunningState](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENPJP.jpg).

If directly changing the voices in Windows Narrator isn't feasible, then is there any work-around I could use to achieve a similar effect? I need to use a 3rd party text-to-speech voice pack for programs that utilize the system voice pack.